# Using jquery and javascript to display variable from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to display a PHP variable using javascript/jquery but it's displaying 'null'.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($checkBan) > 0){
            $bannedDate = $checkBan['banLength'];
            if(preg_match('/[0-9]/',$bannedDate)){      
                list($yyyy,$mm,$dd) = explode('-',$bannedDate);
                 $date = $mm."-".$dd."-".$yyyy;
            }

            //$date = "test"; when this is uncommented it appears in the alert so I know the json_encode is working fine

            ?>
            <script type ="text/javascript">
               var bannedUntil= <?php echo json_encode($date); ?>;
               alert('Your account has been banned until ' + bannedUntil +'. Please contant an administrator if you believe this is an error');
            </script>
            <?

        }
```

The alert appears just fine, but the bannedUntil variable is null. However, when the second date variable is uncommented it appears in the alert. It's not a separate function so I don't see why the scope would be an issue.

Comment: Please stop using the `mysql` series of functions in new applications. This is an interface from the 1990s that is in the process of being retired. New code should use `mysqli` or PDO which will be supported, and also provide reliable [SQL injection protection](http://bobby-tables.com/php) if used properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am seeing you use `$checkBan` as a result resource in `mysql_num_rows()`, then attempt to access an array key from it without fetching. You appear to be missing a call to `mysql_fetch_assoc()`:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($checkBan) > 0){
        // Fetch a row from the result resource $checkBan
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($checkBan);
        $bannedDate = $row['banLength'];
        // etc...
}
```

Another tip: It looks like you are getting a standard MySQL date format back as `YYYY-MM-DD` and converting it with string operations in PHP to `MM-DD-YYYY`. Just retrieve it in that format in your query to begin with and avoid the `explode()` and `list()` calls in your PHP application code.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(banLength, '%m-%d-%Y') FROM yourtable
```